# Scala future combining

Tags: scala

Imagine following variation of InputStream:

```
trait FutureInputStream {
  //read bytes asynchronously. Empty array means EOF
  def read(): Future[Array[Byte]]
}
```

Question is how to write discardAll function for such stream? Here is my solution:

```
//function that discards all input and returns Future completed on EOF
def discardAll(is: FutureInputStream): Future[Unit] = {
  val f = is.read()
  f.flatMap {
    case v if v.length == 0 =>
      Future successful Unit
    case _ =>
      discardAll(is)
  }
}
```

Obvious problem with this code is non-optimizable recursion: it will quickly run out of stack. Is there more efficient solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your solution. The call to `discardAll(is)` is done asynchronously. It doesn't happen in the same stack frame as the previous call, so there will be no stack overflow.

You can kind of see what happens with a naive implementation:

```
trait FutureInputStream {
     var count = 0
     def read(): Future[Array[Byte]] = {
         if(count < 100000) {
             count += 1
             Future(Array(1))
         } else
             Future(Array())
     }
}
```

If you were to feed `discardAll` with an instance of the above, it would be okay.

```
scala> val is = new FutureInputStream{}
is: FutureInputStream = $anon$1@255d542f

scala> discardAll(is).onComplete { println }
Success(())
```